# Why is the function imported from a module significantly slower than a local function in Python?

Tags: python, oop, module

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation for a large set of data, at first I used the statistics module to import the function.

```
from statistics import pstdev
```

But the result is very slow, so I decided to write a local helper method which does the exactly same thing,

```
def get_std_dev(ls):
    n = len(ls)
    mean = sum(ls) / n
    var = sum((x - mean)**2 for x in ls) / n
    std_dev = var ** 0.5
    return std_dev
```

This runs significantly faster! Here are the runtime comparison

```
Runtime with my written function:  0:00:00.532228
Runtime with imported module function:  0:00:17.605583
```

I am very confused why the imported function is so slow compared to my local written function. Does it have to do with memory location?

The only difference between the two functions are the these pieces of codes

```
    stdev = get_std_dev(close_price_list) # my written one
    stdev = pstdev(close_price_list) # the imported function
```

Comment: The library version may be more general than your simple implementation. Have you looked at its source code?

Comment: +1 to what @Barmar said, I had a look at the cpython implementation https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c30388f3c586ba2f33e349e22e5949cb92de621/Lib/statistics.py#L922 and it seems to be handling a lot more cases. How are you measuring the time? Is there a chance you're accidentally measuring the time it takes to import rather than just the execution time? (if you're using timeit from the command line for example)

Comment: @RayanHatout I can reproduce timings consistent with OP's claims using `%timeit` in an iPython REPL. Not the most sophisticated benchmark, but sufficient.

Comment: OP, is there a particular reason you don't want to use `numpy` here? It blows both out of the water.

Comment: I notice the result with the `statistics` module is slightly different; I tried this on a list of 1000 `random.random()` values and got `0.29249153660777805` (module) vs `0.29249153660777777` (handwritten) for the same list. Perhaps it is being more careful about floating-point inaccuracy?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel looks like it has to do with the sqrt at the end. Check the CPython implementation, specifically the call to `_float_sqrt_of_frac()`.

Comment: @ddejohn I tried numpy too. And the run time to calculate the data is approximately the same with statistics module

Comment: @RayanHatout Yes I did take a look at the source code, it is a bit different but doesn't make sense to take so much longer. And I measure the time it took each function to finish processing the data strictly, not including the time to read in data from csv files and importing the module

Comment: How were you using `numpy`? Numpy was *orders of magnitude* faster than yours and the `statistics` module's solutions for arrays up to 10m elements (I didn't test larger than that).

Comment: @ddejohn I imported numpy module on pycharm, if that is what you're asking?

Comment: No I mean the syntax. If `ls` is your data, then `ls.std(ddof=0)` is your population standard deviation. Is that how you were calling the function? Had you converted your data to a numpy array before timing?

Comment: @ddejohn I did convert it to a numpy array. And I used numpy.std(ls) to call it

Answer (score 0):

### This is not an answer

This is just to explain some of my comments more clearly. With `x = np.random.random(10_000_000)` I get these timings:

```py
In [3]: %timeit statistics.pstdev(x)
39.4 s ± 428 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit get_std_dev(x)
4.53 s ± 132 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %timeit x.std(ddof=0)
52.6 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```